# Is there a way for "less" to truncate lines and still exit after < 1 screen?

Tags: less, options

Like many (most), I use git, which by default sends its output (for diffs, logs, etc.) to `less`, with the options `-FRSX`. The options are overrideable in .gitconfig by setting the pager to be called with overriding options. E.g.:

```
  pager=less -F -+S
```

When I set `less` to quit after less than one screen of output and *not* truncate lines (i.e. `less -F -+S` as in the example above), I get automatically returned to my command prompt after I run (say) a `log` command.

However, if I *do* have it chop lines (i.e. use only `less -F`), *and any lines get truncated*, then when it ends, it *doesn't* quit immediately, but prints `END` and waits for me to press <kbd>Q</kbd>, which is somewhat annoying.

(Note that the problematic behaviour does *not* happen if no lines are truncated because they are all narrower than my terminal. The problem is not occurring because it is *asked* to truncate the lines, but that it is actually doing so.)

Is there a way to chop lines and still exit from `less` automatically after less than a screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well... that would be against the idea of paging... wouldn't it? :-)

But to answer your question: I'm pretty sure there isn't. This is from the source code of less:

```
/*
 * The char won't fit in the line; the line
 * is too long to print in the screen width.
 * End the line here.
 */
if (chopline || hshift > 0)  <--- you have chop lines (-S)
{
        ...
        quit_if_one_screen = FALSE;    <--- this resets -F
}
```

Sorry :-)

Comment: Huh, I wonder why.

Comment: Also, can you clarify, "that would be against the idea of paging", please? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Paging is by definition the ability to scroll around when something doesn't fit on the screen and this doesn't. It can be argued whether it's only for "pages" (i.e. lines) but I guess we are not there any more.

Comment: Does `less` support left/right scrolling?

Comment: Yes. When there's horizontal overflow with `-S`, try pressing the right arrow key or `Esc-)` / `Esc-(`. If you press `h` while in less it will show the help for this.

Comment: Ahhh, that clears up the question in my first comment, then: when lines are chopped off, `less` disables `quit-if-one-screen` so that the user still has the opportunity to scroll the text to the left to see what was cut off.

Comment: you can, of course, download the source, comment out that line, recompile it, and install it as `myless` in /usr/local/bin or ~/bin or wherever suits.

Answer (score 0):

Since `less` effectively disables `--quit-if-one-screen` when any line is truncated by `chop-long-lines`, you can't solve this with `less` alone. One alternative it to truncate the lines *before* passing them to less. Something like this:

```
pager = "cut -c -512 | less --quit-if-one-screen"
```

Or, if you want to make it vary according to your terminal width:

```
pager = "cut -c -$COLUMNS | less --quit-if-one-screen"
```